# How to layout character value within R chunk

Tags: r, knitr

In the knitr package I like the kable function. It gives a nice layout of tables and data frame like objects even as it is called from within an R code chunk. Now I want to do the same thing with a character value. Is there a function that gives a kable-like output ("kprint") that can be formated?

```
knitr::kable() # exists for tables
knitr::kprint() # does a function like this exists for character values?
```

This is what I get now:

```
print("character value") # within the R Chunk
```

Output in generated report:

```
## [1] "character value"
```

And this is what I want, just:

character value

*EDIT* cat("character value") is not the solution I am looking for because I don't want an R output anymore, but just a plain text.

Comment: Maybe an example input and example output ? As I really don't get your requirement there.

Comment: @Tensibai, is it clear now? If you still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: `cat("character value")`

Comment: @baptiste, thanks for the suggestion. I don't want it to be R output anymore, but just plain text that I can give a nice lay-out.

Comment: `cat` plus the chunk option `results = 'asis'`?

Comment: @user2706569 I am not sure yet if can alter its layout and add hard returns to it  but I think it's pretty much the result I am looking for. Thanks. If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @user1983395 I added the suggestion as an answer, including some hopefully helpful hints on how to "alter the layout".

Comment: @user2706569, thank you! This is exactly the answer I needed!

Comment: You are very welcome, happy to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to do to get a "raw" character string (without any formatting or additional output like `[1]`) from R to TEX:

- Use the chunk option `results = "asis"` to instruct `knitr` not to modify the output.
- Use `cat` instead of `print` because `print` adds the lenght of the vector and quotes to the output.

In this context, [inline output](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/) using `\Sexpr{}` might be useful because values in `\Sexpr{}` are by default printed "as they are": `\Sexpr{myoutput}`.

As there was the question of how to *format* the output in the comments, here some options:

- Add LaTeX to the text you pass to `cat`: `cat("\\emph{foo}")`. Don't forget to escape `\` by an additional `\`.
- Do the same thing as above, but use a function to do the "dirty work":

  ```
  makeItNiceR <- function(x) {
    return(paste("\\fbox{\\texttt{", x, "}}"))
  }

  cat(makeItNiceR("foo bar is nice"))
  ```

  - (Note that we *could* use `cat` inside `makeItNiceR` to save some typing, but this makes the function less flexible and we cannot use it in combination with `\Sexpr{}` anymore.)
- Manually add LaTeX formatting commands around `\Sexpr{}`:

  ```
  Add formatting to \emph{\Sexpr{myoutput}} directly in LaTeX.
  ```
- Combine `makeItNiceR` and `\Sexpr{}` to get nicely formatted output from `\Sexpr{}`:

  ```
  \Sexpr{makeItNiceR(paste(myoutput, "is nice"))}
  ```

The following minimal examples demonstrates the usage of all code snippets from above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<results = "asis">>=
makeItNiceR <- function(x) {
  return(paste("\\fbox{\\texttt{", x, "}}"))
}

myoutput <- "slim"

cat("foo")
cat("\\emph{foo}")
cat(makeItNiceR("foo bar is nice"))
@

\paragraph{Outside of chunk:} ~\\

\Sexpr{myoutput} \\

Add formatting to \emph{\Sexpr{myoutput}} directly in LaTeX. \\

\Sexpr{makeItNiceR(paste(myoutput, "is nice"))}
\end{document}
```

[image: Generated PDF]