# How to style inline r words when knitr to pdf

Tags: css, r, pdf, knitr

I want to display the following:[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRLZh.png) in a pdf report generated with knitr in R studio. I want keywords red on grey background with a border. I have tried 'mtcars' an different highlighting with no success.

Best regards
Ola Lie
[Edit R Markdown Document Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXmDu.png)

Comment: This SO question should help.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281529/colored-box-just-around-the-text   You could combine its boxing command with something like This is more text \mybox{box}Take the \textcolor{red}{mtcars} data set. \\

Comment: Are you looking for the necessary LaTeX commands (@lawyeR gave a hint on this) or for a way to combine them with variable content in `\Sexpr{…}`? In the latter case, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32369001/2706569) might help.